# Does "especially one who does so constantly" makes sense?

Tags: sentence-structure

Are these sentences correct?

- A ____ is someone who grunts; especially one who does constantly.
- A ____ is someone who grunts; especially one who does so constantly.
- A ____ is someone who grunts; especially one who constantly does so.
- A ____ is someone who grunts; especially one who constantly does.

*so* meaning *in a manner*

blank is for a made up word. *grunt* can be any verb. The structure is what's important.

Is the structure correct? Better options?

Answer (score 1):

Using "so" improves the expression. I would use the second sentence in writing.

Without "so" you may have "one who constantly grunts", the pattern expects a verb to come after the adverb. Since you want to avoid the repetition, using "so" is a good choice. Placing constantly at the end allows for "[end-focus](http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/End-Focus.htm)". The last item in a clause receives weight and focus. It is better, therefore, to end with "constantly" than with "so".

And so, I would choose the second option. However, all four are grammatically correct